# Echo value based on what checkbox is checked

Tags: php

yesHave a simple thing here, but not that handy in PHP. Basically I have a form that will use jquery .ajax submit based on return from PHP script. This is pseudocode for example only

HTML

```
<form id="makepost" name="makepost" action="PHP/wronglish_submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="logged" value="yes">Logged in
    <input type="radio" name="logged" value="no">Not logged in<br>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="sw" id="sw" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if($_POST['logged'] = "yes")  {
    echo "logged";
    die();
    } else {
    echo "not_logged";
    }
?>
```

I know that the first line is not right, can't figure out right way/most efficient way to go about this. I can handle the ajax on the return value, i just can't get it to return the right value.

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=` is assignment.

```
if ($_POST['logged'] == "yes")
```

Comment: damn that was simple. thank you. is that the same as "absolutely equal to" the "=="

Comment: no, `==` is just a plain equality test (values are the same or at least typecast to be the same). in php, `===` is absolute equality test (type AND value are identical).

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a sensitive thing you're doing, use a strict comparison operator for that. `===` and not the assignment one `=`.